# How to change song on next button using YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I want to play YouTube video in any player view But I  can not able to play YouTube video in **MPMoviewPlayer** or in **AVPlayer** thats why I'm using **YTPlayerView**.
And I do not know how to change song when user press next button in **YTPlayer view**. not getting any solution after alots of searching.

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                                 @"controls" : @1,
                                 @"playsinline" : @0,
                                 @"rel" : @0,
                                 @"autohide" : @1,
                                 @"modestbranding" : @1,
                                 @"origin" : @"https://www.example.com",
                                 @"showinfo" : @1
                                };

    [self.youtube_playerView loadWithVideoId:@"w1rRffwXRo" playerVars:playerVars];
    self.youtube_playerView.delegate=self;
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What's the problem with MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: I do not find Onclick next button click. If I found next button click then we can change song on that button click event @SaurabhJain

Comment: So, you should Build a Custom Video-Playback Interface.

Comment: But I have no idea how to create? @SaurabhJain

Comment: OK.. then you can find the how to implement the custom player in Beginning iOS Media App Development Book by Apress publication.

Comment: Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I checked it. but not helpfull . BTW thanks

Comment: Then you should try the AVPlayerViewController. It work fine compare to MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117661/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-saurabh-jain).

Comment: You tube video not work in AVPlayer or MPMoviewPlayer